# tibco rendezvous (tibrv) bitness

Tags: java, 32bit-64bit, tibco-rv

I have multiple different applications with embedded java - some are 32- and other 64-bit on Win 7. I'm trying to use TIBCO Rendezvous in a few of these, the problem is because they use the same PATH they all find 32-bit tibrv and the 64-bit ones just fail to load it. My question is how is this supposed to be addressed?

- Should I have custom path for 64 bit applications (I do have proper installers, so I can do this kind of manipulation at installation time, even if it seems terribly wrong. E.g. copy tibrvj/tibrvnative to its installation directory and use in first in classpath)? If so what do I need to copy, just jars, dlls, both, tibrvnative and/or tibrvj? If I just have maven dependency, is this enough to pull all it needs and to work in this environment (doesn't seem to be the case with tibrvnative implementation I'm using now, but maybe I'm missing something?)
- Is there any difference here if I use tibrvj vs. tibrvnative?
- How does it work in general because as far as I understand there's only one tibrv daemon running and it's spawn by the first process trying to use tibrv, does it matter, will there be more than one process running?

Sorry if all this is answered/documented, I always find it very difficult to find/navigate tibco documentation, seems to me to be tailored to making money on consultancy rather than providing a well documented product.

Environment: Tibrv 8.4.2, Java 8_121, Win 7